# Cannot update Spring Tool Suite from 3.6.3 to 3.6.4 on Win7

Tags: eclipse, windows, spring-tool-suite

Trying to update 3.6.3 to 3.6.4 gives the following errors:

**An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.springsource.sts.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file D:\springsource\sts-3.6.3.SR1\STS.exe failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: D:\springsource\sts-3.6.3.SR1\STS.exe**

I tried unchecking all of the providers except e4.4, but that made no difference.  I know there was a problem uninstalling from C:\Program Files, but I have mine installed in its own directory on a different drive.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: BTW, this is on Luna SR1, 64 bit.

Comment: There is a similar report at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/13, but I have no idea what is going on here. Just for testing purposes: does it happen as well if you install a fresh STS 3.6.3 and update that?

Comment: it looks like this might be related to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=427148, so please take a fresh STS 3.6.4 release and see if that is fixed in newer versions of Eclipse indeed.

Comment: Thanks Martin - I'll just get the fresh 3.6.4 install as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Start STS and before you start upgrading, rename the STS.exe file you just started, to something else, like "STS_old.exe".
That should do it.